# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on Orion Context Broker

Tags: cross-domain, fiware-orion

How to setup Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow cross domain ajax requests on **Orion Context Broker** ver.**0.15.0**

My JS script

```
function capture_sensor_data(){  
var contentTypeRequest = $.ajax({  
      url: 'http://x.x.x.x:1026/ngsi10/queryContext',  
      data: {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "type": "Room",
                    "isPattern": "false",
                    "id": "Room1"
                }
            ]
        },  
      type: 'POST',  
      dataType: 'json',  
      contentType: 'application/json',  
      headers: { 'X-Auth-Token' :'you_auth_token'}  
  });  

  contentTypeRequest.done(function(data){   
     console.log(data);                     
  });                 
  contentTypeRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){     
       console.log( "DEBUG :  Ajax request failed... (" + textStatus + ' - ' + jqXHR.responseText + ")." );  
  });  
  contentTypeRequest.always(function(jqXHR, textStatus){       });
```

};

Response

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://x.x.x.x:1026/ngsi10/queryContext. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://x.x.x.x' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Orion version (0.18.1) doesn't include Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in responses, although probably it will do that in a future version as [it has been identified as a potential feature](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/501).

At the present moment, one possible solution is to use a proxy (placed between Orion and your client) to add that header in the responses from Orion before passing them to your client.

Comment: If you think Orion should suppor Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, please add a "+1" in the comments to https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/501

Comment: THX Fermin, I made a proxy, you can find it at [link](https://github.com/inter-coder/Orion-Web-Proxy-for-Cross-Domain)